# Зависимость числа редукторов от количества узлов кластера

Tags: solaris, unix, map-reduce, java, linux

Моя `hadoop` программа использует один `mapper`, которая разбивает входные данные на определенное число порций, число которых задается в файле `/usr/countcomputers.txt` (читается функцией `mapper`). Далее по одной порции поступает на каждый редуктор. Таким образом число, задаваемое в файле `/usr/countcomputers.txt`, определяет число редукторов. В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос: редукторы выполняются только на компьютерах, на которых запущен демон `TaskTracker`, или на всех узлах, включая те, на которых запущены демоны `NameNode`, `JobTracker` и `Secondary NameNode`? Мне это очень важно знать ответ на этот вопрос, поскольку от него зависит число, задаваемое в файле `/usr/countcomputers.txt`, читаемое в программе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мэпперы и редьюсеры выполняются только TaskTracker'ом.

Comment: @a_gura А зависит ли число репликации в файле `hdfs-site.xml` от количества компьютеров кластера?

Comment: dfs.replication - параметр распределенной файловой системы, который указывает кол-во реплицированных экземляров для каждого файла в HDFS. Для вашей задачи это не актуально.

Comment: @a_gura так если у меня 4 компьютера в кластере, на 2 из которых соответственно запускается `TaskTracker`, то какой должен быть какой коэффициент надо задавать в файле `hdfs-site.xml`
 
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>?</value>
    <description>При создании файла можно задать фактический
    коэффициент репликации.</description>
    </property>

Comment: @ivan31 TaskTracker здесь не при чем. Любой создаваемый в dfs файл будет реплицирован dfs.replication раз.